List Databricks Catalogs from rest API
Trying to query from c# Catalogs from Databricks hosted on Azure using rest API. Everything else works fines SCHEMES / DATABASES / TABLES.
I am using trial version of Databricks, Unity catalog is not enabled and it is non-premium account .
SHOW CATALOGS - shows Spark_catalog only (have Hive_metastore and samples catalogs )
Information.scheme -  also not avaiable.
Are there any method to get the list of Catalogs using rest API?
Thanks in advance.

Even with premium account still the same issue.


It seems like you're encountering limitations with the trial version of Databricks, particularly with accessing catalogs via the REST API. Since the Unity catalog is not enabled and you have a non-premium account, you may not have access to certain features like listing catalogs directly via the REST API.

@VenkatV if I have premium account what would be a proper way to do that ?

Are you searching for a method to list all catalogs in your account using only REST API or any scripts?

@VenkatV Any type of script will help.

Ok. Like PowerShell?

@Adi Azure Databricks REST                                                                                            API reference

@Sampath getting error on second request when populating the proper endpoint Id
{"error_code":"ENDPOINT_NOT_FOUND","message":"No API found for 'GET /sql/endpoints/XXXX/Catalogs/'"}
``

@VenkatV PowerShell , yes.

Ok, let me check and provide you the script.

token=$(az account get-access-token --resource=2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d --query accessToken --output tsv)
curl --request GET "workspace url/api/2.1/unity-catalog/metastores" --header "Authorization: Bearer $token"
For URL :open your workspace and copy the url of the workspace , starting with
URL https://adb.

@VenkatV This is still Unity Catalog. Need the case where unity catalog is not existing/enabled.
public async Task<IEnumerable> List(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
var requestUri = $"{BaseUnityCatalogUri}/catalogs";
var catalogsList = await HttpGet(this.HttpClient, requestUri, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
 catalogsList.TryGetPropertyValue("catalogs", out var catalogs);

 return catalogs?.Deserialize<IEnumerable<Catalog>>(Options) ?? Enumerable.Empty<Catalog>();

}

yes, with Above script, I'm able to fetch Unity Catalog which are not enabled.

@VenkatV Sorry maybe I am expressing wrongly but will try to explain.
When you create databricks (using Premium) you get SQL Warheous, two Catalogs : Samples, Hive_Metastore , no unity catalog is setup. So the question is how to get Catalogs which are not part of UC.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
